# Model is Invalid Because Foreign Key Does Not Exist When It's Created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a `user` table and 2 other tables that each have foreign keys to the `user` table's id field. WhenI create a user, I would like to initialize a record in all three tables, but I'm having trouble doing so. The `user` record is ultimately created, but not the records in the other two tables. After some debugging, I discovered those models were not saved because they were invalid. The error message said, `User must exist`. I'm trying to accomplish the initialization inside the create method:

```
  def create
    logger.info "inside sessions create"
    # how do I save user first, THEN create a record associated with user in 2 tables ? 
    User.where(:id => auth_hash.uid).first_or_create do |user| # finds the matching record in users table
        user.name = auth_hash.info.name
        user.id = auth_hash.uid
        user.token = auth_hash.credentials.token
        user.secret = auth_hash.credentials.secret
      @tweetstore = Tweetstore.new() # Record I'd like to save in Table with Foreign KEY
      @tweetidstore = Tweetidstore.new() # Another Record I'd like to save in a Table with Foreign KEY
      istsvalid = @tweetstore.valid? # returns false
      istsidvalid = @tweetidstore.valid?
      error = @tweetstore.errors.full_messages #USER MUST EXIST
      @tweetstore[:user_id] = auth_hash.uid
      @tweetidstore[:user_id] = auth_hash.uid
      is_tweetstore_save = @tweetstore.save # false
      is_tweet_idstore_save = @tweetidstore.save
    end
    session[:user_id] = auth_hash.uid
    redirect_to '/'
  end
```

How do I restructure my code so that `User` will exist by the time I initialize the other dependant tables? I tried bypassing the problem by adding the `optional` parameter to the models (eg `belongs_to :user, optional: true`) but then I get another error: `QLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`  I'm a newbie at Ruby so please ELI5

Comment: When you use `first_or_create` with a block, the use is not yet created (the block is intended to do things BEFORE it's actually created), don't use the block and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Consider using transactions when you need to create dependent models. When one of the insert fails, let everything that were inserted to DB before that get rollbacked.

Also you should be using `user.id` and not `auth_hash.uid`
ex.

`@tweetstore[:user_id] = auth_hash.uid`

should be

`@tweetstore[:user_id] = user.id`

Also

`istsvalid = @tweetstore.valid? # returns false` its false because it's not yet saved into database.

Comment: actually `auth_hash` is an object returned by `request.env` that contains an id field im using as user id

Comment: try again when user does not exist in Database, You'll get `user.id != auth_hash.uid` .

Comment: in that case a new record would be created and initialized with `auth_hash.uid`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def create
  ...
  #user.id = auth_hash.uid <---- do not set this
  ...
  @tweetstore[:user_id] = user.id
  @tweetidstore[:user_id] = user.id
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

i ditched the `first_or_create` method and just included a condition for the existence of the record. i'm not sure when user is saved in the where block i used above, so i explicitly saved it before saving records in my dependent tables.

```
if !User.exists?(auth_hash.uid)
  @user = User.new()
  @user.name = auth_hash.info.name
    @user.id = auth_hash.uid
    @user.token = auth_hash.credentials.token
    @user.secret = auth_hash.credentials.secret
  is_user_save = @user.save
  @tweetstore = Tweetstore.new()
  @tweetidstore = Tweetidstore.new()
  @tweetstore[:user_id] = auth_hash.uid
  @tweetidstore[:user_id] = auth_hash.uid
  is_tweetstore_save = @tweetstore.save
  is_tweet_idstore_save = @tweetidstore.save
end
```